# SQL Update Segment of 5 Records

Tags: sql, sql-update, row-number

I have a table of names and I want to generate another column "Group" that increases by 1 every 5 records. Below is an example of the desired output.

```
Name    Group
Joe     1
Frank   1
Susan   1
Tom     1
Kim     1
Mike    2
John    2
Henry   2
Rick    2
Quinn   2
```

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?  And how would like to order these people in order to generate a grouping (there needs to be an order I believe)?

Comment: I am using MS SQL Server 2014. They can be order alphabetically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a CTE with row number will help

```
;WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT 
    Name,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Name) AS RowNum
  FROM YourTable
)

SELECT
  Name,
  (RowNum - 1) / 5 + 1 AS [Group]
FROM cte
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
   select a.name,
   case when (a.myrow%5=0) then 5 else a.myrow%5 end as group 
   from 
   (select name,row_number() over (order by name) as myrow from YourTable)a
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach

```
Create table #tmpNames
(
    Name1 varchar(100)
)

Insert INTO #tmpNames
(Name1)
VALUES
('Joe'),
('Frank'),
('Susan'),
('Tom'),
('Kim'),
('Mike'),
('John'),
('Henry'),
('Rick'),
('Quinn')


Select Name1
    ,ROUND(rowCnt / 6, 0, 1 ) + 1 as 'grp'
From (
    Select
        Name1
        ,ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Name1) as 'rowCnt'
    From #tmpNames
    ) a
```